# What's the difference, between int* and int*[]

Tags: c++

```
void test(int* integers, int n) { ... }
void test(int* integers[], int n) { ... }
```

What is the difference? They both are pointer to int and can be used as an array. When to use the first, for example?

Comment: They're not both "pointer to int".

Comment: "What's the difference between a banana and an apple? They're both bananas"

Comment: The latter is equivalent to void `test(int** integers, int n) {}`.

Comment: "They both are pointer to int" - not even close. The first one is. The second one is a pointer to pointer to int, but only because it's inside a function argument list. If it wasn't, it would be an array of pointers to int. And neither of them "can be used as arrays", since they are not arrays but pointers, and arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays, and you can't parse HTML using regular expressions, and you should not cast the return value of malloc, and...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.


Comment: I feel like the wrong "hold" reason was chosen: *"This question does not appear to be about programming"*... **Really?**

Comment: @CodyGray The wording of the new closure reasons is **bad.** It's just inappropriate. The problem with this question is really that it's an RTFM (a. k. a. "too localized") one. It's on-topic, but apparently the SO staff s'en fout.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm rather satisfied with this one and use it often: *Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work.* I'd complain about the new close reasons, but Jeff Atwood has shamed me repeatedly about complaining every time people move my cheese. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, I tend to use that one as well... the only reason I'm not bringing this up to Meta is that I don't want to loose all my meta rep (all that 243 anyway... :P)

Answer (score 5):

`int*` is a pointer to `int`. It is not an array, but it may represent a start address of an array (or an array iterator — a position inside of an array).

`int*[]` is an *array of pointers* to `int` (**not** array of `int`s!). Because we're in context of function arguments, it is ok to have empty brackets (i.e. array of unknown size), which effectively makes this parameter a *pointer to pointer to `int`*.

---

Have you meant "what's the difference between `void test(int* integers)` and `void test(int integers[])`"?

*As function arguments*, `type arg[]`, `type arg[SIZE]` and `type* arg` are the same *to the compiler* and mean actually `type* arg`.

For a programmer who reads your code:

- `type arg[]` gives a *hint* that `arg` should be a pointer which represents start address of an array.
- `type arg[SIZE]` gives a *hint* that `arg` should be a pointer which represents start address of an array of the specified `SIZE`. Note that the compiler ignores `SIZE` and doesn't perform any bounds checks.

Comment: `int*[]` is *not* an array in this context, never. It wouldn't be even if the size were specified.

Comment: Removing my downvote, cheers.

Comment: @jrok: thx for constructive hint!

Answer (score 2):

In the declaration of a variable, the difference would be the following:

```
int* integers;
```

This is a declaration of a variable of type `int*`, which is a pointer to an integer.

```
int* integers[x];
```

This is a declaration of an *array* of x *pointers to `int`*.

However, in the context of declaring function arguments, the array syntax is only syntactic sugar for declaring a pointer, with a hint to whoever reads the code that the pointer will be used as an array.

Hence:

```
void test(int* integers[], int n) { ... }
```

In this declaration, `test` takes a *pointer* to a *pointer to `int`*. If any size had been put inside the square brackets ([]), this would have been completely ignored by the compiler and `integers` would have still been treated as an ordinary `int**`.

In other words, this is equivalent to:

```
void test(int** integers, int n) { ... }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
void test1(int* integers, int n) { ... }
void test2(int* integers[], int n) { ... }
```

You can pass parameters to them like:

```
int arr[10];
void test1(arr, 10) { ... }
```

And

```
int arr2D[5][5];
void test2(arr2D, 10) { ... }
```

`int *integers[]` as in function param will decay as `int **integers`

`*` means point->value while
`**` means points->address->value.
Also note that (in stack) it just points to the base address i.e the first index of the contiguous memory location

Comment: -1 because a 2D array doesn't decay to `int**`.

Comment: @jrok I didn't say 2D array will decay to `int **arr`. I am just referring to function parameter, not `arr2D[5][5]`.

Comment: I know what the declaration means. But you're passing `int[5][5]` to a function that expects `int**` and that's what's wrong.

Comment: @mr5 Yet it's not the same as `int (*)[5]` which `int [5][5]` decays into. Only the first (innermost) dimension of an array decays into a pointer. What you wrote is incorrect.

Comment: Okay my bad... I think we all got the number `2` here (not including the sign)

Answer (score -2):

In order to understand the difference i will explain this:

when you send an int array to a function, you can do it like this:

```
int arr[5]={7,6,4,7,8}
myFunction(arr,5)
```

the function prototype will look like:

```
void myFunction(int* arr, int size)
{
   //...
}
```

or

```
void myFunction(int[] arr, int size)
{
  //...
}
```

there is actually no difference between int[] or int* in a function prototype.

if you are passing a 2 dimensional int array you can do it like this:

```
int rows=3, cols=4;
int arr[rows][cols];
//... fill your array
myFunction2(arr,rows,cols);
```

the function prototype will be:

```
void myFunction2(int[] arr[cols],int rows, int cols)
{
   //...
}
```

or

```
void myFunction2(int* arr[cols], int rows, int cols)
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: This is wrong too, see my comment on mr5's answer.